# Symfony2 Form Event PreSetData Subscriber

Tags: php, forms, symfony, doctrine-orm, symfony-forms

In my Application the user can create Custom Fields for some entities and then set the values for this custom fields for each entity object when i display a form.

The implementation is like this:

1º) I created a Interface for the forms, and the forms that i want implement this Interface.

2º) I created a form extension for all forms:

```
app_core_form_builder.form_extension:
        class: App\Core\Bundle\FormBuilderBundle\Form\FormExtension
        arguments: ["@service_container", "@doctrine.orm.entity_manager"]
        tags:
            - { name: form.type_extension, alias: form }
```

3º) In this extension if the form implements the interface referenced in the step 1 i add a EventSubscriber:

```
if($formType instanceof \App\Core\Bundle\FormBuilderBundle\Model\IAllowCustomFieldsdInterface){
             $builder->addEventSubscriber(new FormSubscriber($this->container, $this->em));    
}
```

4º) This Form Subscriber subscribes the preSetData FormEvent. In this method i get the Entity associated with the form and i get all custom fields created for it.
Then i add this fields to the form with the help of Symfony2 Form Type.
Everything goes well, and when i display my form the custom fields are rendered correct. Just for the record, when i save the form the values inserted in the custom fields also are store well.

```
public function preSetData(FormEvent $event) {

        $data = $event->getData();
        $form = $event->getForm();


        // During form creation setData() is called with null as an argument
        // by the FormBuilder constructor. You're only concerned with when
        // setData is called with an actual Entity object in it (whether new
        // or fetched with Doctrine). This if statement lets you skip right
        // over the null condition.
        if (null === $data) {
            return;
        }

        $formEntity = $form->getConfig()->getType()->getInnerType()->getEntity();

        $DbEntity = $this->em->getRepository('AppCoreSchemaBundle:DbEntity')->findOneBy(array('id' => $formEntity));

        if ($DbEntity && $DbEntity->getAllowCustomFields()) {

            $organization = $this->container->get('app_user.user_manager')->getCurrentOrganization();

            if (!$organization) {
                throw $this->createNotFoundException('Unable to find Organization entity.');
            }

            $params = array(
                'organization' => $organization,
                'entity' => $DbEntity,
            );

            $entities = $this->em->getRepository('AppCoreSchemaBundle:DbCustomField')->getAll($params);


            # RUN BY ALL CUSTOM FIELDS AND ADD APPROPRIATE FIELD TYPES AND VALIDATORS
            foreach ($entities as $customField) {
                # configurate customfield

                FieldConfiguration::configurate($customField, $form);
                # THE PROBLEM IS HERE
                # IF OBJECT IS NOT NULL THEN MAKE SET DATA FOR APPROPRIATED FIELD
                if ($data->getId()) {

                    $filters = array(
                        'custom_field' => $customField,
                        'object' => $data->getId(),
                    );

                    $DbCustomFieldValue = $this->em->getRepository('UebCoreSchemaBundle:DbCustomFieldValue')->getFieldValue($filters);
                if ($DbCustomFieldValue) {
                    $form[$customField->getFieldAlias()]->setData($DbCustomFieldValue->getValue());
                } else {
                    $form[$customField->getFieldAlias()]->setData(array());
                }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

The problem is when i try to edit a form. if you look at the part in the code above where says "THE PROBLEM IS HERE" you can understand.

If the object of the form has an ID, then i will get the values stored for the custom fields of that object, and i call $form[field_alias']->setData(value returned from database that is mapped as type Array).

But this dont work, and the Data is not set for the fields. But if in my controller i do the same, the data is set properly.

Does anybody have an idea where the problem can be? Can't i set the data in preSetData Event?

**EDITED**

The value field from the Entity DbCustomField is mapped in this way:

```
/**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="value", type="array", nullable=true)
     */
    protected $value;
```

`

`var_dump($DbCustomFieldValue)` -> object(Ueb\Core\Bundle\SchemaBundle\Entity\DbCustomFieldValue)

```
var_dump(DbCustomFieldValue->getValue())
```

-> string(11) "bruno valor"

But even if i try something like:

`var_dump($customField->getFieldAlias());` = string(21) "testebruno-1383147874"

`$form[$customField->getFieldAlias()]->setData('example1');` it doesnt work.

But in my controller if i do the following for the fieldAlias above:

```
$form['testebruno-1383147874']->setData('example2');
```

-> it does work

Any idea?

Comment: i dont see anythin extrange in your code, try to debug it with die(var_dump($data)) so we can see what is your data array value

Comment: a few days ago i cross with the same issue, and i managed to solved it by changing the form event, when you set a value in a preSetData event then symfony2 will set the data and it may change what you set before in the preSetData event, change the event to postSetData if you can, thats how i solved it so i hope that will work for you to.

Comment: thanks man, i will try with postSetData Event

Comment: @metalvarez i tried with the postSetData event and it works as i expected. Thanks for the tip ;)

Comment: ok @joao alves dont forget to post the solution in code

Comment: @joaoalves I've posted metalvarez as answer, to have your question answered ;)

Answer (score 1):

As [metalvarez](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1978737/metalvarez) suggested [in his/her comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19691951/symfony2-form-event-presetdata-subscriber?rq=1#comment29312371_19691951) and [working as expected](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19691951/symfony2-form-event-presetdata-subscriber?rq=1#comment29450255_19691951), use the `postSetData` event instead of the `preSetData` one:

```
public function postSetData(FormEvent $event) {
    // ...
}
```

The `preSetData` event method is called before populating the form with default values, then Symfony2 will set the data and it may change from what you set before, thus the use of `postSetData` instead.

[image]

*Figure [from the doc](http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/form/form_events.html)*