# Unset form filed value Symfony 2

Tags: php, forms, symfony, events

I try to unset field values, but I cant do that, there is related post on [stack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19691951/symfony2-form-event-presetdata-subscriber), but there is no answers.
Here code what I try:

```
$builder->addEventListener(FormEvents::PRE_SET_DATA, function (FormEvent $event) {
        $event->setData(array('category' => null));       
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What are you trying to achieve with `PRE_SET_DATA` listener?

Maybe you could do the same with something like this?

```
$builder
    ....
    ->add('category', 'some_form_type', array(
        ....
        'data' => NULL,
        ....
    )
    ....
```

Comment: thanks, i just dont knew about data option) need to read docs more closely.